# Rewrite or change routing in asp.net MVC URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rest, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to be able to rewrite my URL's to a single level URL. This means that i need to make a dynamic(will change in each language) rewrite rule, like this:

Original Url: http://www.mydomain.com/account/pages/13

I always want to show the URL in a single level:

http://www.mydomain.com/my-page-title

never no more than one slash / after the domain name.

I also need to be able to translate the page title in the above example:

http://www.mydomain.com/my-translated-page

How do I achieve this, and it should be able to change this on runtime - that is to "improve" the url, just like rewrite rules in htaccess

Comment: So, MVC generally wants you to be restful so this sounds like a terrible idea at first glance. It might help to know why you're trying to accomplish this? I have a few ideas, but I'm not sure how appropriate they would be based on the info given here.

Comment: SEO reasons - need to roll out in multiple countries and have a simple  URL structure.

Comment: Restful uris are inherently seo friendly. Why note add the culture/locale to the route itself (e.g. www.mysite.com/de/Home). Typically, the way we handle lanugages in .net is to receive either a parameter like this or read the accept-language header and set the UICulture for the thread. Translated pages are the same base as the original pages but resource files are switched based on the UICulture

Comment: Yes, but in SEO the URL is important. The example: Im running a webshop selling clothes, in particular pants. In one language i want to make a url: www.pantshop.com/pants/checkered-pants in another country i want to make it www.trousersshop.co.uk/trousers/checkered-trousers, and so forth in any language. The important part is to get the keyword in the url.

Comment: Using such a localized URL scheme is still possible without rewriting. You can add the language to the route and the localized page title. The value of the routes should be parsed at runtime to map them to a particular page.

Comment: For the translating of the URL you can take a look at this blog http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx

Comment: @BrianHvarregaard, what do you think of StackOverflow's SEO-Friendly design? They use the 1st 2 params for actual navigations and redirect to a keyword slug appended? BTW, having done SEO for almost a decade, I can assure you that the "level" at which keywords appear is not important. (it was somewhat circa 2006)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own `Routes`. As you are using the `MVC4` put this custom route above the Default Route of the Application.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Custom_Route",
      url: "My-Page-Title/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

And for [**translating a Url in Mvc**](http://www.manas.com.ar/spalladino/2011/01/20/translating-route-names-in-asp-net-mvc-2/)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a simple and easy to answer question. Complete description can't be placed here. But I try to guide you with some suggestions and Links may be useful. Considering that with The default form of MVC Routing is `/controller/action/id`, we'll ensure **uniqueness** of each part during programming and help of database's unique `Id`s, In this way, no need to pay attention on uniqueness of each part And routing is infallible **always**.

By the way, First of all, ensure you'll generate **non-repetitive URLs** to be caused ambiguity in Routing. *So each Page title should be unique!*

After that you need to have [lower cased and dashed page titles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseDashedRoute/). Or write following code to put the title to lower case and replace non-alphanumeric characters with dashes to employ in routing implementation.

```
public static string SeoName(string name)
{
    return Regex.Replace(name.ToLower().Replace(@"'", String.Empty), @"[^\w]+", "-");
}
```

Finally you need to have **Translation provider** `Interface` to use in Routing. See [Translating routes](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx) Article to implement this feature too.

**Note** that you must order routes according to their priority as desired to perform in order subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own custom routes like this,
This should be the first route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default_Custom",
                url: "MyCustom-{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and make sure that you have this line in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This woks for the all request like `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")`

But the request like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Will be handled by the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```